# How to Snap/Align Verticies at an Angle

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, vertices, faces, edges

I'm making this model and as I'm tweaking and making adjustments, the straight lines start becoming a little jagged. Now, I know about the trick to flatten a set of verts or faces by Scaling on the Z axis and hitting 0. But my un-flattened faces are at a 20ish degree angle. And I need it to be at 20 degrees rather at a flat 0. How would I make a set of vertices snap or align to each other and remain at the same angle they're at currently?

Picture reference on what I mean below.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

## You can scale the edges with a custom Transform Orientation with two axes locked.

- Select some edge that has an orientation that you are happy with.
- Once it is selected press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to make(and activate) a new custom Transform Orientation from the edge. The newly created Transform orientation will have its Y axis going along the length of the edge.
- You can now select all the edges that you wish to straighten. You could manually select them or use some tools from the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> menu, or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click to select the shortest path between two edges and check Face Stepping option in the bottom of the <kbd>t</kbd> panel or the <kbd>F6</kbd> panel.
- You need the pivot center for scaling to be set to Individual Origins in the Header of the 3d View for this to work.
- Then you just hit <kbd>s</kbd> for scaling, hit <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> twice to constraint scaling operation to the x and z axes of the selected Transform Orientation only and hit <kbd>0</kbd> to scale them to 0.

[image]